# nginx too many redirects (cloudflare and https)

Tags: nginx, django, cloudflare

Hello and thanks for the help.

I've searched and found similar issues, but not what I'm experiencing. I'm getting "Too many redirects" when trying to configure nginx to serve my app.

This is the :80 server config

```
server{
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name app.domain.com;

    location /{         
        # This is an acceptable config: If request went trought http, 
        # redirect to https server
        if ($scheme = "http"){
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }

        # This is what i REALLY want: If request went trought http (this
        # server is listening port 80) and the user agent does not match,
        # then redirect to https, else show a specific html 
        #if ($http_user_agent !~* "SPECIFIC USER AGENT" ) {
        #   return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        #}
        #if ($http_user_agent = "SPECIFIC USER AGENT" ) {
        #   return 301 https://app.domain.com/specific.html;
        #}
    }

    location /specific.html {
        root /home/htmls/;
        autoindex off;
    }


    # This is required for the acme challenge oof Let's encrypt
    location /.well-known/acme-challenge {
        alias /etc/letsencrypt/webrootauth/.well-known/acme-challenge;
    }

}
```

This is the https server :443

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name app.domain.com;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/app-access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/app-error.log;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/app.domain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/app.comain.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_read_timeout 90s;
        proxy_connect_timeout 90s;

        #proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    }
}
```

I've configured my webserver app to add a SSL certificated. The site is behind cloudflare protection (but disabled for this specific sub-domain). I'm working with let's encrypt certbot. My app worked just fine, I've renewed the certificated a few times, but this last one the "too many redirects" issue appeared.

I've tried almost evertything, several cloudflare crypt configurations. I can answer to almost every scenario you could ask me. The results are always a "too many redirects", or an unaccesible site.

Please help me! this is driving me crazy :S

Comment: What does `curl -v` show when requesting the URL of your site?

Comment: Please edit your post to show the command line and output headers of "curl -i ". Please also clarify "disabled CloudFlare security" - is it still a proxy, or is it just doing DNS? Does the site work with CloudFlare just doing DNS (orange cloud clicked so it goes gray, wait an hour to test). You need to give us more information. Also, you don't need the "if https" in your http block, just redirect everything on port 80.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of letting all of your severs do the rewrites on the domains, why not let Cloudflare do this with its traffic rules. Simple rewrite http://* -> https://*

Obviously you can customise this however you want and add in any error pages etc that you would want to display to the user - but is much quicker to implement this here and reduce the amount of traffic hitting the origin servers as a result.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Yes CF page rules can do redirection, but I find it best to do it on the server. This leaves page rules to be used for other things, like tweaking caching.

Comment: I am only giving it as a suggestion to reduce server load and one option to resolve the issue. By all means you don't have to do it this way.

Comment: Redirects are't typically a significant load. The unnecessary "if" around the redirect would increase load very slightly.

Comment: I personally prefer to do the most amount of config on a cloud based app in preference to server based as it is faster to adapt and update to any situation. But I agree with you in that its not going to be a massive load.